# Using Material UI and Creative Tim Material Dashboard Pro together

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Using Creative Tim Material Dashboard 2, I want to include a  Component coming from @mui/material/Tabs

When the component is rendered, I want to have the original Material UI style applied, not the Creative Tim's one.

Original Material UI style:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwOpj.png)

When included in Creative Tim app:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZC7lH.png)

And more generally, I'd like to be able to swith within a component, ie.:

```
return (
        <Grid container spacing={3}>
      <Grid item xs={12} md={12} lg={12}>
        <MBButton variant="contained" color="success" sx={{ mr: 1 }}> Test Button </MBButton>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={12} md={12} lg={12}>
        <useMaterialUIStyling>
          <Box sx={{ borderBottom: 1, borderColor: 'divider' }}>
            <Tabs value={value} onChange={handleChange} aria-label="basic tabs example">
              <Tab label="Item One" {...a11yProps(0)} />
              <Tab label="Item Two" {...a11yProps(1)} />
              <Tab label="Item Three" {...a11yProps(2)} />
            </Tabs>
          </Box>
          <TabPanel value={value} index={0}>
            Item One
          </TabPanel>
          <TabPanel value={value} index={1}>
            Item Two
          </TabPanel>
          <TabPanel value={value} index={2}>
            Item Three
          </TabPanel>
        </useMaterialUIStyling>

      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

How can I achieve this ?